# Join on tables with no records

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have 3 tables:

```
Employees
{
  EmployeeID
  EmployeeName
}

AttSattus
{
  StatusID
  StatusName
}

AttendanceRecords
{
  RecordID
  Date
  TimeIn
  TimeOut
  StatusCode
}
```

I need a procedure to to select records for whole month, i.e. for 31 days if record for an `Employee` is not in db then he/she must be with Absent status final output should look like this:

```
Date, Employee Name, Time In, Time Out, Status
```

Currently I am using temp tables that have performance issues very slow.
Please guide.

Thanks in Advance
Rashed

Comment: Please include current solution here

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your data correctly, currently there is no logical data correlation between tables.

Attendance record should have a EmployeeID and a StatusID and then you can join your other tables to Attendance Record